# What's wrong with this Modulo in Python 33

Tags: python, python-3.3

```
from math import *

def prime():
a = 0
b = 0
x = 2*a+1
y = b

for a in range (1,5000) and b in range (0,5000) and y<x :
    ctr = 0
    if (x % y == 0):
        ctr += 1
        return [None]
    else:
        primes = (x)
        ctr+= 1
        return [None]
    print (primes[999]);
```

I have a problem I need to solve but when it gets to the modulo ( %) sign it says TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable"

Comment: `for a in range (1,5000) and b in range (0,5000) and y<x :`?!?

Comment: @Andra V Please do not edit your question to the point that the original answers become not understandable. Instead, please [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead. That way, people with the same problem benefit from the answer as well. Don't worry, questions are free. Thanks!

Comment: I've rolled back the question.  Andra V, as @phihag explained, if you edit the question into something else, the answers become incomprehensible.  If you have a separate question, open a new question.  StackOverflow works using a question/answer format, with specific and discrete questions, not a threaded forum-style format where there's a long back-and-forth until all related problems are solved.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing the values, you are assigning 0 to `x % y`, which is not possible. You can fix it like this

```
if (x % y == 0):
```

After fixing that,

```
for a in range (1,5000) and b in range (0,5000) and y<x :
```

this line will not work, you have to split the loops like this

```
for a in range (1,5000):
    for b in range (0,5000):
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: for a in range (1,5000) and b in range (0,5000) and y<x :
   TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable  when I did that, that's the error it gives me

Comment: I thought about that, but first I wanna make the modulo line working :D thanks though

Answer (score 1):

The modulo sign is fine, note the `^` in the error message.

```
  File "so-modulo-test.py", line 11
    if (x % y = 0):
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`=` indicates an [assignment statement](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt). You want `==`, the [equal comparison operator](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html?highlight=comparison#not-in), as in

```
if x % y == 0:
```

Additionally, `and` is the logical AND, and not to be confused with how a human would talk. Your loop should look like:

```
for a in range (1,5000):
    for b in range (0, x):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you... I did from math import * at the beginning, so it should have worked...

Comment: The modulo operator is always available. In any case, an `import` does not change syntax, it only binds names. Also, note that the problem is completely unrelated to the modulo operator.

Comment: So the fact that I get the boolean error is related to the for statement and only that?

Comment: @AndraV Correct. If you play close attention, you see that the `bool` error occurs when the program runs, whereas the original syntax error occurred even before that. That's because `range (1,5000) and b in range (0,5000) and y<x` is simply evaluated to a truth value (`True` in this case), and we call the truth type [boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) after its [inventor George Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole).